# DiscriminatorMap Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

When upgrading an application from Symfony 3 to Symfony 4 I ran into a memory issue.  I've tracked it down to a used `DiscriminatorMap`. A little pseudo code:

`/**
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "\App\Entity\Person"})`

If the Class is found a memory error occurs.

Has something changed regarding DiscriminatorMaps?

PHP: 7.2.3
Symfony: 4.0.6